# Getting Text value on RadioButton From Another Class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I want to get radio button text on buttongrup from another class for painting. 
 I Create an object and called string radio but gives error. Whats wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class Demo extends JFrame{

 /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Demo(){

     getContentPane().add(new Panelalt(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     getContentPane().add(new Panelust(),BorderLayout.NORTH);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

  static void createAndShowGUI() {

    Demo f = new Demo();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new Panelust());
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    f.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class Panelalt extends JPanel  {
JComboBox numbers ;
private JRadioButton rectangle;
 private JRadioButton line;
 private JRadioButton circle;
 private JRadioButton square;
  ButtonGroup grup;
  JLabel number;
JButton draw ;
int gotnumber;
int gotheight;
int gotwidth;

String radio="";


public Panelalt(){
    grup = new ButtonGroup();

     rectangle = new JRadioButton("Rectangle");
       rectangle.setActionCommand("Rectangle");
      square = new JRadioButton("Square");
      square.setActionCommand("Square");
       line = new JRadioButton("Line");
       line.setActionCommand("Line");
       circle = new JRadioButton("Circle");
      circle.setActionCommand("Circle");
      rectangle.setSelected(true);
      JButton draw = new JButton("Draw");

      grup.add(circle);
       grup.add(line);
       grup.add(rectangle);
       grup.add(square);


       draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                radio=grup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
            }
        });

}

   }
 class Panelust extends JPanel{
Panelalt user = new Panelalt();

public Panelust(){

}
```

Called other class obj. here

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(user.radio.equals("Rectangle")){
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop sabotaging my edits!  -1

Comment: `public void asd(Graphics g)`??

Comment: think that public void paint(...)

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a read through;

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

So you can gain an appreciation for how painting is done in Swing.

Next, make your `Drawing` class extend from `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (not the `paintComponents` method, which does something completely differently)

Use this class to perform the custom painting only, do not add any controls to it.  Supply appropriate setters and getters to allow to control what is painted.

Create yourself a new `JPanel` and add your controls to this.

Add both these panels to an instance of `JFrame`.

There are lots of reasons why you should do this...

- Top level containers like `JFrame` are not double buffered, meaning that repaints will flicker, so you want to avoid overriding the `paint` methods.
- Painting is complex series of chained method calls, breaking any part of the paint chain without good reason is going to lead you into a world of pain (as you tear your hair out trying to figure out what's going wrong)
- Painting onto a component that already has components on is going to end up painting underneath the components.  Even you tried overriding `paint`, because individual components can repainted without notifying the parent container, they will appear to "pop" over what you have painted.